# problems with installation pycrypto in python 3.6

Tags: pycrypto, pysnmp, python-3.6

I've tried to install pysnmp (which uses pycrypto) on python 3.6.0 using pip, but I've got an error:

> Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import
>   setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:
>   \Users\HOME-M~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6l69kxa5\pycrypto\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'op en', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec')) " install
>   --record C:\Users\HOME-M~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-qq93gmf_-record\install-record.txt
>   --single- version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HOME-M~1\AppData\Local\Temp\p
>   ip-build-6l69kxa5\pycrypto\

I'm not an advanced user, and I've not been able to come up with a solution for this problem. Please tell me if you know how to resolve it.
Python 3.5.2 easily allowed installation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try [PyCryptodome](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome) which is a drop-in replacement for now-obsolete PyCrypto.

```
$ pip install pycryptodome
```

Alternatively, if you'd take the [latest pysnmp](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp), it explicitly depends on Pycryptodome.

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp.git
```

Or just download zipped package, unpack it into a local dir and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: Cool, Thanks. I just don't know how to deal with packages, except downloading them via "pip install"

Comment: Just added a note on on pip installing from github.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works :) I should've  learn python packaging system better :)

Comment: ``pip install pycrypto`` failed for me too, but ``pip install pycryptodome`` worked. Then I went to ``%appdat%\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages``, and copied ``pycryptodome-3.4.6.dist-info`` to ``pycrypto-3.4.6.dist-info``. Seems to work for the library I'm using that depends on pycrypto.